# Rewrite multiple sub-directories to the same path htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite multiple sub-directories to the same path. while I can remove a part from URL Apache htaccess

for example, I want

domain.com/category/computer/internet-topics

domain.com/category/computer/windows-topics

domain.com/category/science/physics-topics

domain.com/category/science/biology-topics

to be

domain.com/category/internet-topics

domain.com/category/windows-topics

domain.com/category/physics-topics

domain.com/category/biology-topics

When I use this, it works fine for the first line only (computer)

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ category/computer/$1

RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ category/science/$1

Comment: If a piece of information is required for your routing to work correctly, then you can not just remove it from the URL completely and without substituting it for something else. If I requested `/category/foobar`, how is your system supposed to know whether that is actually supposed to be in the category `computer` or `science`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to be specific else only first rule will be used

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/((internet)|(windows)-topics)$ category/computer/$1
RewriteRule ^category/((physics)|(biology)-topics)$ category/science/$1
```